# Set view backgroundcolor with MonoTouch.Dialog

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

since a couple of days I'm trying to set the background of a MonoTouch.Dialog to blue ...
I collect a lot of information while searching like this one [How to set the background to transparent on a DialogViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9977427/how-to-set-the-background-to-transparent-on-a-dialogviewcontroller)
and this [UITableView backgroundColor always gray on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688007/uitableview-backgroundcolor-always-gray-on-ipad) but I can't make it work for my usage ...

What I like to do is to create a DialogViewController for my root element with a blue background and this is what I'm doing:

```
        _rootVC = new DialogViewController (_rootElement);
        _rootVC.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;
        _rootVC.View.Opaque=false;
        _rootVC.TableView.BackgroundColor=UIColor.Blue;
        _rootVC.TableView.Opaque=false;
        _nav = new UINavigationController (_rootVC);
        _window.RootViewController = _nav;
```

The root element is fine the whole code works - only no more idea why I can't change the background color ...
Can you help please?

Thanks

Andre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```cs
_rootVC.TableView.BackgroundView = null;
```

By default `UITableView` with grouping uses blue background with white lines. It uses `BackgroundView` property.